# Bad results after introducing new data to a trained and restored Tensorflow model

Tags: python, variables, tensorflow, restore, prediction

I built a NN based on "[Binary classification, soerendip](https://github.com/soerendip/Tensorflow-binary-classification/blob/master/Tensorflow-binary-classification-model.ipynb)" to continuously predict binaries. The following code is the simplification of the training procedure:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

X, Y = make_classification(n_samples=50000, n_features=10, n_informative=8, 
                           n_redundant=0, n_clusters_per_class=2)
Y = np.array([Y, -(Y-1)]).T  # The model currently needs one column for each class
X, X_test, Y, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y)


# Parameters
learning_rate = 0.001
training_epochs = 12
batch_size = 1
display_step = 1


# Network Parameters
n_hidden_1 = 10 # 1st layer number of features
n_hidden_2 = 10 # 2nd layer number of features
n_input = 10 # Number of feature
n_classes = 2 # Number of classes to predict


# tf Graph input
x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_input], name = 'x')
y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_classes], name = 'y')

# Create model
def multilayer_perceptron(x, weights, biases):
# Hidden layer with RELU activation
    layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['h1']), biases['b1'])
    layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(layer_1)
    # Hidden layer with RELU activation
    layer_2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['h2']), biases['b2'])
    layer_2 = tf.nn.relu(layer_2)
    # Output layer with linear activation
    out_layer = tf.matmul(layer_2, weights['out']) + biases['out']
    return out_layer

# Store layers weight & bias
weights = {
        'h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_hidden_1])),
        'h2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2])),
        'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2, n_classes]))
        }

biases = {
        'b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1])),
        'b2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2])),
        'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))
        }

# Construct model
pred = multilayer_perceptron(x, weights, biases)

# Define loss and optimizer
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=pred, labels=y))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)

# Initializing the variables
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

# Launch the graph
saver = tf.train.Saver()
#export_dir="/tmp/new"
#builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder(export_dir)

#if low_level == True:
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    # Training cycle

    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        avg_cost = 0.
        total_batch = int(len(X)/batch_size)
        X_batches = np.array_split(X, total_batch)
        Y_batches = np.array_split(Y, total_batch)
        # Loop over all batches
        for i in range(total_batch):
            batch_x, batch_y = X_batches[i], Y_batches[i]
            # Run optimization op (backprop) and cost op (to get loss value)
            _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: batch_x,
                                                      y: batch_y})
            # Compute average loss
            avg_cost += c / total_batch
        if epoch % display_step == 0:
            print("Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch+1), "cost=", "{:.9f}".format(avg_cost))
        print("Optimization Finished!")


    save_path = saver.save(sess, "/tmp/model.ckpt")
    print("Model saved in path: %s" % save_path)
```

For restoring and testing I use the following function:

```
def restoring(X_test,Y_test):

    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph("/tmp/model.ckpt.meta")
    with tf.Session() as sess:

        #now restore the variables
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        saver.restore(sess, "/tmp/model.ckpt")
        #print("weightsh1",weights['h1'].eval())
        #print("weightsh2",weights['h2'].eval())        
        #print("weightsout",weights['out'].eval())        
        #print("biasb1",biases['b1'].eval())
        #print("biasb2",biases['b2'].eval())        
        #print("biasout",biases['out'].eval())  

        #np.savetxt("weightsh1_check.txt",weights['h1'].eval())
        #np.savetxt("weightsh2_check.txt",weights['h2'].eval())        
        #np.savetxt("weightsout_check.txt",weights['out'].eval())        
        #np.savetxt("biasb1_check.txt",biases['b1'].eval())
        #np.savetxt("biasb2_check.txt",biases['b2'].eval())        
        #np.savetxt("biasout_check.txt",biases['out'].eval()) 

        #coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        #threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
        aa = []
        for ss in np.arange(len(X_test)):

            aaa = X_test[ss]
            aaa = aaa.reshape(1,10)
            aa.extend(sess.run(pred,feed_dict={x: aaa}))
        #coord.request_stop()
        #coord.join(threads)
        aa = np.array(aa)
        bb = np.argmax(aa,1)
        cc = Y_test[:,1]
        dd=np.equal(bb, cc)

        accur_val = np.sum(dd)/len(X_test)
        print('Accuracy of validation:')
        print(accur_val)
```

The accuracy is usually >90% and the variables are also restored as wished. In my real world example, I am facing the following challenge: At first I am using time-series data from an api which is updated every minute. Unfortunately, it involves confidential data, however, this example might be enough to understand the problem even though`make_classification()` is not perfect for it. If it is not good enough, please comment below and I will figure something out. 
When I am using the following flow, restoring works fine:

1. Download data
2. Train model
3. Restore and test model
   --> good test restults

When I use the following flow, the accuracy usually falls significantly.

1. Download data
2. Train model
3. Restore and test model (good results)
4. Download new data, restore and test model (Bad results, randomly between 40-60%)

The test size is usually around 200 minutes so that the first api download results in:

data_test_input[t200]=[d0,d1,...d200] with good results (>90%).

When the model is trained and tested successfully the first time, I download again some updated data which looks like e.g. this:

data_test_input[t203]=[d3,d4,...d203] with bad results(40-60%)

I would usually assume, that I have at least an accuracy of around the previous value, however, it turns out to be randomly set every time. What could cause this issue or am I doing something wrong?

Thank you very much in advance!